# Why position relative isn't working?

Tags: css

I have a sidebar on the page that should look like this 
[image: Menu]

but What I get is this

[image: actual menu]

The submenu doesn't show as it should, my code look like this

```
.submenu{
    position: absolute;
}
.submenu ul{
    height: auto !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
.submenu ul li{
    position: static !important; 
}
```

When I assign `right: value` the behavior of the component is not usual. [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLe7D/1/embedded/result/)

Thank you!

Comment: One reason it is display like that is because nothing is hiding it to be revealed.

Comment: I don't see "position:relative" or "right:value" in the code you provided. You appear to be using "position:absolute".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got this to work but not in the fiddle you provided. When making a fiddle for a question on overflow try to isolate only the code that pertains to the question or problem. When you add everything in there it makes it a little hard to find the related material.

I made a fiddle for you to show how it works and if you like how it is then feel free to just use that. This is a css dropdown and doesn't require any scripting. What you need to do is nestle a `ul` inside of the main `ul's` `li` tag. You then have to hide the nested ul to later be revealed on a hover action.

The triangle I made does not have to be a CSS3 triangle, you can use an image.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sideBar">
<ul>
    <li>¿Porqué Nosotros?</li>
    <li><span class="tri"></span>Pregrado
        <ul>
            <li>Diseño &amp; Comunicación Visual</li>
            <li>Comunicació y Relaciones Públicas</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Posgrado</li>
    <li>Maestría</li>
    <li>Calendario</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.sideBar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
}

.sideBar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sideBar ul li {
  height: 20%;
  width: 180px;
  padding:  10px 0 10px 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.tri {
  content: "";
  border-top: 19px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  top: 20%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}  

.tri:after {
  height: 38px;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.sideBar ul li:hover .tri {
  display: block;
}

.sideBar ul li:hover {
  background: red;
}  

.sideBar ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 100%;
}

.sideBar ul li ul li {
  background: #7b7b7b;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 260px;
}

.sideBar ul li ul li:hover {
  background: black;
}

.sideBar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle you can use for a visual reference.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Rv82/1/)

If you need more help then let me know.